# :not selector does not exclude expected elements

Tags: css

There is HTML content like this:

```css
table {
  margin: 16px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

:not(.exception) table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table></table>
    <div class="exception">
      <table></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In my understanding, `:not(.exception) table` should set the background color of the `table` element outside the `.exception` class to red, while the `table` inside `.exception` should still show the inherited green. like this:

[image]

But in reality, the background color of the `table` element inside the `.exception` class has also changed to red. Why is that?

[image]

## Additional questions?

When I change `:not(.exception) table` to `.container :not(.exception) table`, all the tables change from red to green again, why? Or is there a better way to exclude the influence of external CSS on the internal `table` of `.exception`?

Comment: `:not(.exception)` select any element that hasn't the specified class so it's selecting more than what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

> In my understanding, `:not(.exception) table` should set the background color of the `table` element outside the `.exception` class to red,

No, the `:not(.exception) table` rule matches all elements with the tag name `table` that are a descendant of an element that matches `:not(.exception)` (all elements that do not have the class `exception` applied).

`body` is, for example, an element that matches `:not(.exception)`, and every `table` is a descendant of `body`, and due to that `:not(.exception) table` matches every `table`.

You could use `:not(.exception) > table` instead, because `>` limits the relationship between those elements to be child and parent.

Comment: Oh I see, `:not` will look up all the ancestors of the `table`, and then the `body` doesn't have a `.exception`, so the element is selected. Thank you very much for your quick answer!

Comment: @hopgoldy Yes, you have different [combinators and separators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors), the "space" in  `A B` is a descendant combinator, so `B` is the descendant of `A` (or `A` the ancestor of `B`). And due to that `:not(.exception)` is `A` in that case, and it looks for all ancestors of `B` which is `table` in that case.

Comment: @hopgoldy it is not only `<body>`  that matches, also `<div class="container">`  and `<html>` (any ancestor with that does not have `.exception`).